# Upload file to Google drive using cron executed PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to upload a 50MB file upload to a folder on my Google Drive account.

Algorithm:

1. Cron triggers PHP - PHP dumps MySQL database and compress and encrypt file;
2. Same PHP script triggers another script and supplies file name. This script should use Google Drive API to upload the file to my Google Drive account.

Then file should be available on my Google Drive as `blahblahblah/backup.sql.tar.gz`

But it isn't. And I'm sure that everything fails on part where upload is ended - no output.

I don't even know how the hell I'm supposed to get client secret? I tried dev console but I only get:

```
CLIENT ID
CERTIFICATE FINGERPRINTS
API KEY
```

I have tried so far:

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples

And also this:

```
<?PHP
/**
 * Insert new file.
 *
 * @param Google_DriveService $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
 * @param string $description Description of the file to insert.
 * @param string $parentId Parent folder's ID.
 * @param string $mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
 * @param string $filename Filename of the file to insert.
 * @return Google_DriveFile The file that was inserted. NULL is returned if an API error occurred.
 */
function insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename) {
  $file = new Google_DriveFile();
  $file->setTitle($title);
  $file->setDescription($description);
  $file->setMimeType($mimeType);

  // Set the parent folder.
  if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
  }

  try {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);

    $createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => $mimeType,
      'uploadType' => 'media'
    ));

    // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    // print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();

    return $createdFile;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

I use the latest Google API PHP Client Library.

Can I get simple PHP code which will work out of the box utilizing the API and uploading the file?

There are no user actions involved. I do not need to authorize user. 
Everything should be done on server side.

Comment: You say "I repeat, there is NO USER actions involved." but of course at some point the user (even if it's you) has to authorize the app (even if it's your app) to access your Google Drive. This is a fundamental part of OAuth. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_web. In the code you posted how did you create the $service object? When debugging OAuth/Drive, it's always worth trying to dump the http packets to see what's going over the wire, and any responses.

Comment: As it is MySQL backup, and it's done on server side completely, I want to make PHP which will utilize Google API to upload file to Google drive. This should be done by cron every 12 hours, so if for example something happens with my server, backup will be on Google drive ready for deploy on new location.

Comment: I know what you want to do. My question is, how did you go about authorizing your app to be able to access your Google Drive? I suspect you haven't correctly understood how OAuth works.

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/project/APPNAME/apiui/credential# | And there: Create New client ID > Service account

Answer (score 2):

Client Secret is for Web applications, where multiple or single users have to sign in to give authorization. Your case needs a service account, where a single account handles everything and only needs certain parameters that can be coded in your scripts.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("xxxxxx.json"), true);

$CLIENT_ID = $json['client_id'];
$CLIENT_EMAIL = $json['client_email'];
$REDIRECT_URI = "";
$private_key = file_get_contents('xxxxxxxx.p12');
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $CLIENT_SECRET,
    $SCOPES,
    $private_key

);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("appName");
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
```

Fill in the x's with your files, make sure to download the .json and .p12 so the script can read it. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

To get Client ID and Public Key, You need to register your app: [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=drive).

For detailed documentation Please visit: [Google Drive realtime API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart#step_1_activate_the_drive_api).

Comment: Not exactly.... I finish up with same useless data: only client ID and API key and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: have you tried setting up the sample as the tutorial shows? I've no apps registered with them. I am up voting your question, so that someone experienced with Google app may help.

Comment: Just a update I got some progress, upload success but:
- Binary file get damaged because of string "MIME TYPE" in begining of file. (Inserted by Google Drive)
- I cannot specify file name but it is saved as "Untitled" instead.